# Will a USB Memory Stick Solve memoryerror in python?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, networkx

This is kind of a dumb question, but I really have doubts about whether this will work before I go buy a usb drive. I'm getting a memory error while doing community detection on a large graph.  The algorithm needs to hold the whole graph in memory as well as the communities that it finds.  If I reduce my adjacency matrix by about 10-20% I don't run into a memory error.  So there's nothing wrong with my code per se. I just need a tiny boost to the system it is running on.

It was at this point that I thought if I only had a couple of gigs of more ram I could do this analysis on the full graph. Which would be ideal. Then I thought about buying a usb memory stick and dedicating it for increasing performance.

The only problem is that it is acting as a cache not as true RAM, so I don't know if it will solve my problem. Even if it doesn't it may still work because it will cache things from background programs?  Or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: A pendrive is not RAM, it operates much like a hard disk instead. Something like Windows ReadyBoost can help, but unlikely. Maybe you can increase your pagefile or modify your code to put temp variables in a file instead of memory.

Comment: Make sure that the graph names are definitely integers.  That saves a lot of memory relative to strings.  (and realize that if you read it in from a text file and don't explicitly tell it to convert to integers they may be stored as strings.  For example `'8'` rather than `8`).